# How do I enable the libreoffice quickstarter in unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, libreoffice, notification-area

I would like to get my quickstarter to show in unity, or replace it with an indicator. Is this possible?.

I tried Unity 2D, and to my shock, it works there, but refuses to work in unity proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by whitelisting `all` applications and restarting my computer. Seems unity (3D) needed a few updates to make it work correctly).

NB: I was also able to get it to work with a somewhat crude method of whitelisting:

- `soffice.bin, Soffice.bin, soffice --quickstarter, soffice.bin --quickstarter Soffice --quictkstarter, Soffice.bin --quickstarter`

I'm not sure which one exactly did it, but I would have to do further testing with individual values to find the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mess with the DConf editor, there is a list of applications that are white listed for working in Unity's partial notification area. However, as for getting an indicator there are none that come to mind.

[For your perusal.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-hide-or-show-app-tray-applets-in-ubuntu-11-04/)

Answer (score 0):

How to solve this question under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ? There are no `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist` opportunity like suggested here - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-hide-or-show-app-tray-applets-in-ubuntu-11-04/