# Why computer dosent shut down, reboot or log out when i start Libre Office Quick Starter

Tags: libreoffice

Why computer dosent shut down, reboot or log out when i start Libre Office Quick Starter? And when libre office quick starter is working can i logout or shut down computer?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34796/how-do-i-enable-the-libreoffice-quickstarter-in-unity

Comment: @viyyer I disagree, as that question is asking how to enable Quick Starter while this one is asking how to shutdown/reboot/log out once it is active. At any rate, this is a known bug and hence offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

Because of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/562027 .

- [How do I subscribe to a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug)